# Search not displaying results when html special characters used

Tags: catalogsearch, search

On our store we have a category "Maços" and that word is also on description of many products.

When this word is searched no results are found. I already went to catalog search options and tried the options "LIKE" and "Fulltext" and both combined with no luck...

What you do when you face this situation?